# How to include a variable that conditonally counts over the rows of a data set in R?

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks like this

```
Topic1 <- c("Drinks", "Food", "Dress", "Drinks", "Food")
Subtopic1.1 <- c("Beer", "Pizza", "Red", "Beer", "Pizza")
Subtopic1.2 <- c(NA, NA, NA, "Wine", "Fries")
Topic2 <- c(NA, "Drinks", "Drinks", "Dress", NA)
Subtopic2.1 <- c(NA, "Beer", "Beer", "Black", NA)
Subtopic2.2 <- c(NA, NA, "Wine", NA, NA)


df1 <- data.frame(Topic1, Subtopic1.1, Subtopic1.2, Topic2, Subtopic2.1, Subtopic2.2)
```

For every row, I want to count how many Subtopics there are for a certain Topic. Goal is to include - for every **topic** named - a variable that counts the number of subtopics that are named for the topic. For example, the variable `Drinks_count` counts all subtopics related to drinks for a certain row.

I think explaining works better with an example. So let's take row 5. Under `Drinks` there are 2 subtopic mentioned `Beer`and `Wine`. Therefore, `Drinks_count` should provide the number `2`. For the same row, the topic `Dress` is present with subtopic `Black`. Therefore, `Dress_count` should provide the number `1`.

Desired output:

```
Topic1  Subtopic1.1 Subtopic1.2 Topic2  Subtopic2.1 Subtopic2.2 Drinks_count    Food_count  Dress_count
Drinks  Beer        NA          NA      NA          NA          1               0           0
Food    Pizza       NA          Drinks  Beer        NA          1               1           0
Dress   Red         NA          Drinks  Beer        Wine        2               0           1
Drinks  Beer        Wine        Dress   Black       NA          2               0           1
Food    Pizza       Fries       NA      NA          NA          0               2           0
```

I'm open for dplyr solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using mostly functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df1 %>%  mutate(row = row_number()) 

df1 %>%
  left_join(df1 %>%
  #Get the data in long format keeping data of Topic and Subtopic 
  #in different columns using pivot_longer
  pivot_longer(cols = -row, 
               names_to = c('.value', 'num'), 
               names_pattern = '([A-Za-z]+)(\\d)') %>%
  #Remove NA values
  filter(!is.na(Subtopic)) %>%
  #fill the Topic column with previous non-NA value
  fill(Topic) %>%
  #For each row count how many subtopics are present
  count(row, Topic) %>%
  #get data in wide format and join by original data.
  pivot_wider(names_from = Topic, values_from = n, 
              names_prefix = 'Count_', values_fill = 0), by = 'row') %>%
  select(-row)

#  Topic1 Subtopic1.1 Subtopic1.2 Topic2 Subtopic2.1 Subtopic2.2 Count_Drinks Count_Food Count_Dress
#1 Drinks        Beer        <NA>   <NA>        <NA>        <NA>            1          0           0
#2   Food       Pizza        <NA> Drinks        Beer        <NA>            1          1           0
#3  Dress         Red        <NA> Drinks        Beer        Wine            2          0           1
#4 Drinks        Beer        Wine  Dress       Black        <NA>            2          0           1
#5   Food       Pizza       Fries   <NA>        <NA>        <NA>            0          2           0
```

Comment: Thank you. This translated perfectly to my real data set and worked like a charm

Comment: I've send you a coffee via your buymeacoffee, but forgot to include my username